# Installing Unsupported Versions of Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, installation, windows-10

I am going crazy trying to figure out what I thought be a simple process. I want to use a module of python that is only supported on python 3.4 (I currently have 3.9). My process so far:

1. Went to python website and tried to find an installer for python 3.4
2. They did not have installers, only a tar.gz
3. Downloaded Python-3.4.10.tgz
4. Extracted it to Python-3.4.10.tar
5. Attempted to run `python setup.py install` and got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`
6. Went to PCBuild and read the readme.
7. The readme told me to download Visual Studio and build the `pcbuild.sln` in Visual Studio
8. Installed Visual Studio 2019
9. Opened the `pcbuild.sln` file and attempted to build, got errors

Also tried doing this with venv / virtualenv, but how do I actually install python 3.4 with these? I also tried `pip install Python-3.4.10.tgz` which didn't work either.

Ideally I'd like to have both 3.9 and 3.4 side by side. Is this really such a complicated process that requires multiple other software to work? I feel like I am going crazy

Comment: Have you tried using the module with Python 3.9?

Comment: Yes, it does not work

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows installers available here? https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-344/

Comment: Oh wow I guess 3.4.10 just doesn't have any installers available. I guess the question is solved then.

Comment: Once a Python version goes into security-fixes-only mode, it is only released as source.  3.4.4 was the last installer-provided version.